# How to make a Post request with "content type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"?

Tags: node.js, angular, oauth-2.0, http-post

I need to make a request to get a toke in oAuth2 authentication server.

I can make the request in postman and get the token, can't make the same request from angular 4.

My CORS is well-configured cause other requests are working perfectly.

Here are the details of HTTP request.

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Authorization: Basic YXBwbGljYXRpb246c2VjcmV0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 9f9582e9-fe73-499f-d7f7-82498a974e39

grant_type=password&username=pedroetb&password=password
```

In angular 4, I tried this way

```
let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    headers.append("Authorization","Basic YXBwbGljYXRpb246c2VjcmV0");

    var obtainTokenUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/oauth/token';

    this._http.post(obtainTokenUrl + "?grant_type=password&username=pedroetb&password=password", null, {headers: headers}).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

But this is not working.

This is the screenshots of the postman request
Headers:
[image]

Body:
[image]

So how can I make this same request from angular 4?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple code for retrieving data of users. See, headers are given as header options. You can view more in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#configuring-other-parts-of-the-request)

```
createUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
    const submittedUser = JSON.stringify(user); // user is form-submitted data object
    const headers = new Headers ({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return this.http.post(baseURL + 'user/create', submittedUser, options)
      .map((response: Response) =>  {this.processHttpmsgService.extractData(response);})
      .catch(error=> Observable.throw(error));
  }
```

[Docs for HeaderOptions](https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptions)

Comment: I can make the plain api request, but can not figure out, how to send a request with all these header and form data like application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Answer (score 0):

PostRequest(url:string,data:any) {

```
var headers = new Headers();

let req = JSON.stringify(data);

 this.onRequest("request: " + url + "data: " + req);

headers.append ("content-Type","application/json");
headers.append("charset","utf-8;");
headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
headers.append("Authorization","Bearer "+ token);

 let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
console.log(options);

  // don't have the data yet
 return new Promise(resolve => {

   this.http.post(url,req,options)
   .map(res => res.json())
   .subscribe(data => {
     resolve(data);

     this.onSuccess(data);
  }
  ,error => {
 this.onError(error);
  }
  );
});
```

}

also do not forget to import 
import {Http, Headers,RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

Comment: When I make the request, I don't have the token. It's for getting the token. Actually how I send the grant_type, username, and password?

Comment: this.http.post(tokenURL,"username="+username+"&password="+ password + "&grant_type=password", { headers: headers })

Comment: I  tried that way. But It sends me "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=pedroetb&password=password. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400"

Comment: sorry but seems you should check your service method, since it is working fine solution for me.

Comment: At line 7 there's a token required. But in this request, I asked the server to provide me a token.

Comment: also sent you a token request at one of my comments, nothing changes just headers & parameters. The code above is generic for post method.